# saving tags ( comma seperated ) in database column for django app makes it slow for big DB

Tags: django, database, postgresql, search, full-text-indexing

to In my django app, based on some criteria my system will be generating `tags`. and one book will be marked with multiple tags.

currently in book table, I am storing tags as comma separated values.

```
 class books(models.Model):
  book_id = models.AutoField(primary_key=True, auto_created=True)
  search_tags = models.TextField(default='[]')
```

in the data base tags will look something like below.

```
HUPB,CWGL,ABNG,USXQ,CEXV,BYPC
```

but when i have search it back using tags, i have to use `search_tags__contains('ABNG')`
which works.
But now my database expected to grow big and there can be more then 100 unique tags for a book and there can be million books in my db.

this looks a very common problem, so would like to know if someone can suggest a good technique to achieve the same.

Answer (score 1):

The proper pattern for this is to use a many-to-many relationship to a separate Tag table.

```
class Tag(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=4)

class Book(models.Model):
    tags = models.ManyToManyField(Tag)
```

Now you can do `Book.objects.filter(tags__name='ABNG')`.

(Note, Django model names should be singular and start with an upper case letter.)